# Are there any .NET equivalents to Node.js?

Tags: asp.net, .net, node.js

I'm aware of Dan Newcome's partial implementation of Node.Net (port of Node.js using JScript.Net) though it seems like he has seized development on it. Are there any other single-threaded (or multi-threaded) event-driven servers in .NET?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to [look](http://jacksonh.tumblr.com/post/1159500924/manos-de-mono-the-manifesto) at [manos](https://github.com/jacksonh/manos).