# Use ASP.NET with node.js

Tags: asp.net, node.js, webserver

is there any way to use asp.net and node.js together?

I don't thinks so because node.js is a whole different webserver?

Edit for clarification: i want to add websites, based on node.js to an existing asp.net web forms application

Comment: check this <a href="http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/10/26/using-node-js-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application-with-iisnode.aspx"> MVC Architecture and node.js togather </a> and also check this <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/a/4570844/1557322"> Stack </a>

Comment: This question makes no sense, you should describe more what it is you want to accomplish. If your question is if you can run them on the same server, the answer is yes. But you would need Mono (if linux/osx server) or iisnode (if windows server)

Comment: @christian-wattengard: technically iisnode is not a requirement to run node on windows. you can go with the "stock" binary.

Comment: Well yes... But the question on what he is trying to accomplish is still ambigous at best ;)